# What is the difference between stable ∞-categories $\text{perf}_ZX$ and $\text{perf}~Z$

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, infinity-categories

Let $X$ be a quasi-compact quasi-separated scheme and $Z$ a closed subscheme.

One has a symmetric monoids stable infinity categories $\text{perf}_ZX$, which is generated by perfect complexes supported on $Z$.

Is there a functor from $\text{perf}_ZX$ to $\text{perf}~Z$, or from $\text{perf}~Z$ to $\text{perf}_ZX$?

Comment: Pullback to $Z$ gives a functor from the category supported on $Z$ to the category on $Z$. Push forward gives a functor going the other way under some hypothesis on the inclusion morphism - I think lci is enough.

Comment: No, the composition would be a tensor product with the Koszul complex. Even for the inclusion of a point into a smooth curve the pullback and pushforward functors don't give an equivalence.

Comment: @Sawin Shortly after I commented, I realised my silly question and deleted my comment…..
Thank you very much